# Laravel - Creating a website to imitate estimatemyapp.com, can't get input from radio buttons and checkboxes?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm currently stuck on how to get input from radio buttons and check box and calculate their value? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h4sB.jpg)

```html
<h1>5.{{$result}} Dates & Locations</h1>
@foreach ($dates as $product) 
  <li>
     <input type="radio" name="get" id="{{$product->id}}" 
            value="{{$product->price}}" />
     <label for="{{$product->id}}">
        <img src="{{URL::asset($product->image)}}">
     </label>
  </li>
@endforeach

<h1>6. Social & Engagement</h1>
@foreach ($social as $product) 
   <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="5" 
             id="{{$product->id}}" value="{{$product->price}}" />
      <label for="{{$product->id}}">
         <img style="border-radius:50%;" 
              src="{{URL::asset($product->image)}}">
      </label>
   </li>
@endforeach
<span id="price" data-format="$ 0,0[.]00" 
      data-formula="($1+$2+$3+$7+$8+$9+$10+$11+$12+$13+$14+$15+$16+$17+$18+$19+$20+$21+$22+$23+$24)+(($4+$5+$6)/100*($1+$2+$3+$7+$8+$9+$10+$11+$12+$13+$14+$15+$16+$17+$18+$19+$20+$21+$22+$23+$24)) " readonly="readonly" class="readonly">$ 0
</span>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: your form is not complete .. there is no opening `div` and `form` tags.

Comment: in my original code it is, I just posted a small snippet to give an idea of how my blade template looks like

Comment: You mean that you can't get the input values in the controller or you can't get them to display in the view? I'm lost.